# SpagoBI Server is not Running

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory, connection-timeout, spagobi

We are very new to SpagoBI tool and selected this tool for performance enhancement of an existing application developed using MS BI tool. We are facing problems which is given below.

Issue Description : When we try to publish a template in running Spago BI server we could see the following exceptions and the Spago BI server gets stopped. SpagoBI is running in a Linux box. The hardware specification is 2CPU, 3 Ghz, 4GB RAM and 160GB harddisk.
1. In Web Browser : Connection TimeOut exception is seen 
2. In Logs : OutOFMemory exception is seen 
Actions Taken: Heap memory space is increased but no luck. 
We have to restart the machine where this Spago BI server is installed to make it up and running again.

Root Cause: We are not able to determine. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, i upgraded my ubuntu jdk to 1.8+ and the heap exception OutofMemory was gone.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory allocation pool size for the JVM through the -xmx parameter (go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) for the explanation of what xmx means).

You can do that by adding this line

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

at the top of the script bin/catalina.sh